# javascript dynamic image content highlight not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

`<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="assets/img/a.png" id="ltri" height="200" width="200">
<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="assets/img/a1.png" id="ltri1" height="200" width="200">`

**JavaScript**

```
 function loadimg(tag){
var myimg = new Image();
myimg.src = 'assets/img/'+tag+'.png';
$("#ltri").attr("src",myimg.src);
// -- image 2
var myimg = new Image();
myimg.src = 'assets/img/'+tag+'1.png';
$("#ltri1").attr("src",myimg.src);
}
// After Loading image (A for APPLE, B for Ball) Audio Played
$("#ltri").css(
{
    "background-color": "none",
    "animation-name": "example",
    "animation-duration": "3s"
}
);
setTimeout(function(){
$("#ltri1").css(
{
    "background-color": "none",
    "animation-name": "example",
    "animation-duration": "3s"
}); 
}, 3000);
```

now i want to change background on every **loadimg()** call.
but its not working only once change background, not on every call.

```
<li onclick="loadimg('a')">A for: Apple</li>
<li onclick="loadimg('b')">B for: Ball</li>
```

Page **ScreenShoot**
[See Image of my working Page but not Highlighting Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H59k.jpg)

While Playing Audio (A FOR apple(img **a**), A for Ant(img **a1**).
 i want to highlight apple (image 1) in first 3 seconds of audio 
 other 3 second ANT mean (image 2)
full audio consist of 6 second for two images
Please Help how is this possible to change background for highlight ?

Comment: can't you just move the setTimeout into the loadimg function?

Comment: i want to change background one by one single single image after one another not at the same time so thats why i put some sleep time between them using setTimeout() But its not working for me Please Help

Comment: Where do you call `loadimg()`? Can we see the code for your animation? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful for us to visualize your goal.

Comment: you will need to put the setTimeout inside a "foreach" to display them one by one.